# Azure Kusto Spark override ingestion_time() in write

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-data-explorer

I'm writing data to Kusto using [azure-kusto-spark](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark).

When writing to Kusto, the `ingestion_time()` (by default) returns the time records are ingested.

How do I change this date to a different one?

I tried with creationTime and dropByTags. No luck so far.
Example below with dropByTags (I want to change the `ingestion_time()` to let's say '2021-06-19')

```
sp = sc._jvm.com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasink.SparkIngestionProperties(False, ['2021-06-19'], None, None, None, None, None, None)

df.write. \
  format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource"). \
  ...
  option("sparkIngestionPropertiesJson", sp.toString()). \
  mode("Append"). \
  save()
```

Using pyspark with jar `com.microsoft.azure.kusto:kusto-spark_3.0_2.12:2.7.4` in Azure databricks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ingestion_time()` is the UTC datetime at which the record was ingested, as measured by the service. It can't be overridden, regardless of which client API or ingestion pipeline you're using.

Overriding `creationTime`, which you referred to above, allows to you make sure retention and caching policies (which are measured based on the time of the data shard's creation, that you can override) get applied accordingly.

You may want to clarify what's the scenario in which overriding `ingestion_time()` would be required.